# indexed order by is slow when doing inner join

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I am trying to join two simple tables with `ORDER BY` clause

Tables:

**Alerts**:

- *Total Rows:* `690000`
- *Indexes:* `(createdAt DESC, id DESC)`

**SubscriptionFeed**:

- *Total Rows:* `99990`
- *Indexes:* `(createdAt DESC)`

The problem is when I add `ORDER BY a."createdAt" DESC, a.id DESC` the query becomes much slower than using `ORDER BY sf."createdAt" DESC`

The query I need and it's explain plan

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT a.id, a."createdAt", sf."name" 
FROM "Alerts" as a
INNER JOIN "SubscriptionFeed" as sf
ON a.id = sf."alertId"
ORDER BY a."createdAt" DESC, a.id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

**Explain Plain:**

```
"Limit  (cost=0.84..81.54 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=7.926..5079.614 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..403440.05 rows=99990 width=24) (actual time=7.923..5079.604 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using idx_created_at_uuid on "Alerts" a  (cost=0.42..69639.05 rows=690000 width=24) (actual time=5.897..3697.758 rows=630013 loops=1)"
"              Heap Fetches: 630013"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using "SubscriptionFeed_alertId_subscriptionId_key" on "SubscriptionFeed" sf  (cost=0.42..0.46 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=630013)"
"              Index Cond: ("alertId" = a.id)"
"              Heap Fetches: 20"
"Planning Time: 30.234 ms"
"Execution Time: 5079.773 ms"
```

The query with `ORDER BY sf."createdAt" DESC` and it's explain plan

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT a.id, a."createdAt", sf."name" 
FROM "Alerts" as a
INNER JOIN "SubscriptionFeed" as sf
ON a.id = sf."alertId"
ORDER BY sf."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 20
```

**Explain Plan:**

```
    "Limit  (cost=0.84..28.91 rows=20 width=32) (actual time=1.785..2.708 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..140328.41 rows=99990 width=32) (actual time=1.784..2.703 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using idx_subscription_feed_alert_id on "SubscriptionFeed" sf  (cost=0.42..6582.83 rows=99990 width=24) (actual time=1.705..2.285 rows=20 loops=1)"
"              Heap Fetches: 20"
"        ->  Index Scan using "Alerts_pkey" on "Alerts" a  (cost=0.42..1.34 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=20)"
"              Index Cond: (id = sf."alertId")"
"Planning Time: 3.758 ms"
"Execution Time: 2.865 ms"
```

Comment: Why do you join `SubscriptionFeed` when you don't select any of its values?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I updated the answer, actually it's part of a query but I don't understand this behavior

Comment: Your query plans are identical, but show different rowcounts. They also dont match your "table definitions"

Comment: @wildplasser: No, they are not. Look at which table gets accessed first. The first plan shows many `Alerts` rows being selected and then the nested loop join of `SubscriptionFeed` until 20 result rows are reached. The second plan shows 20 `SubscriptionFeed` rows being selected and then the nested loop join to retrieve their 20 `Alerts` rows.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Postgres is finicky about the ordering of keys in the index.  I would recommend writing the query as:

```
SELECT a.id, a."createdAt" 
FROM "Alerts" a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM "SubscriptionFeed" as sf
              WHERE a.id = sf."alertId"
             )
ORDER BY a."createdAt" DESC, a.id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Then including the following indexes:

- `SubscriptionFeed(alertId)`
- `Alerts(createdAt desc, id desc)`.

Comment: This is not helping at all, here is a part of explain plain `->  Index Only Scan using idx_created_at_uuid on "Alerts" a  (cost=0.42..69639.05 rows=690000 width=24) (actual time=0.016..4162.390 rows=630022 loops=1)`

Comment: @Muhammad: You had Gordon confused by only selecting from `Alerts`. He surmised that you selected the rows multifold by mistake or you saw it somewhat guaranteed to find no more than one `SubscriptionFeed` row for an `Alerts` row. This is why he suggested to use `EXISTS` instead to get a proper query.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation seems easy. You are joining two tables, `Alerts` and `SubscriptionFeed`. And you want to see the twenty result rows with the highest dates. Every `SubscriptionFeed` row belongs to an `Alerts` row, but not every `Alerts` row has necessarily related `SubscriptionFeed` rows.

So, when you want the latest `SubscriptionFeed` rows, that's easy: Take the last 20 `SubscriptionFeed` rows (from the index), join their 20 `Alerts` rows and you're done.

When you want the latest `Alerts` instead, the DBMS will take the last `Alerts` row, join all its subscriptions, check if it already got twenty rows, if not, then take the next `Alerts` row, again join all its subscriptions, check whether twenty rows are reached, and so on. Well, the DBMS may use another algorithm, but it will never be as simply as the one for the latest `SubscriptionFeed`.

That's it. It is not likely we can get the `Alerts`query nearly as fast as the `SubscriptionFeed` query. But we can think about how to help the DBMS accessing the rows: Your existing index on `Alerts(createdAt DESC, id DESC)` helps the DBMS to quickly find the latest `Alerts` rows. In order to get their related `SubscriptionFeed` quickly, you'd want an index on `SubscriptionFeed(alertId)`. (Well, maybe you have that already, given that `SubscriptionFeed.alertId` references `Alerts.id`.)

Apart from that you can provide covering indexes, containing all columns from a table you are using in your query (i.e. add the other columns to the already mentioned indexes), e.g.:

```
create index idx on SubscriptionFeed(alertId, name);
```

Comment: So there is nothing I can do to improve the query and this would keep getting slower as the Big O Notation is `O(n)`?

Comment: Apart from what I've already said, you may be able to provide an appropriate `WHERE` clause, e.g. only select alerts created this year, month, week, well, whatever seems reasonable. You may end up with less than 20 rows then, but this may be okay with you.

Comment: Actually, what I want is to have latest alerts created so what would happen if I select current month and the alert was created before that?

Comment: Then you wouldn't get it of course. It would be the same, if you selected all alerts in 2018 and 2019, but the last alert was in 2017. So the question is, can you decide for a restriction you are fine with? Another restriction I can think of would be something along the lines of: show the latest, say, 10 alerts, no matter how many subscriptions they have and how many more result rows you hence end up with.

Answer (score 1):

I've explained the issue in my other answer. Here is a thought on how to speed up the query.

Your query gets the latest alerts with their subscriptions. You cut at twenty result rows, thus possibly ending up with some randomly picked ones (e.g. if the two latest alerts had 15 subscriptions each, you'd select all subscriptions for the latest alert and pick five random ones for the other alert).

We don't know how many different alerts will be in the result. But we know it's never more than 20. So, here is something you could try:

```
select a.id, a.createdat, sf.name 
from (select * from alerts order by a.createdat desc, a.id desc limit 20) as a
inner join subscriptionfeed as sf on sf.alertid = a.id
order by a.createdat desc, a.id desc
limit 20;
```

What this query does is: select the latest 20 alerts first. Then inner join the subsriptions. Thus we end up with at least 20 rows, but it could be 100, 1000 or a million, depending on how many subscriptions there are per alert. (I consider it likely, though, that are or not *that* many suscriptions per alert, so there shouldn't be that many rows to join.) At last we limit the result again in order to end up with no more than twenty.

Indexes:

- alerts (createdat desc, id desc)
- subscriptionfeed (alertid)

(This query shouldn't actually make a difference to your own query, for it's obvious that there cannot be more than 20 alerts in the result. But maybe it helps the optimizer see this. It's worth a try, I guess.)